# Find all the $x$ such that $N \mod x = 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Find all the $x$ such that $N \mod x = 1,$ where $x < N$ and $N$ is a big integer.

Please help me find a solution, or tell me if this is not a simple task to do.

Comment: $N \bmod x=1$ means  $x$ divides $N-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, this solves my questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$N \bmod x=1$ means $x $ divides $N-1$,

so finding all the $x$ such that $N\bmod x=1$ is as hard as factoring $N-1$.